# One .htaccess file per domain

Tags: apache

Can you have more than one .htaccess file per domain / web site in the directory files/folders or do you really just need one? Can you have multiple .htaccess files per web site.
Shaun b

Comment: You can have multiple htaccess on your server but only one per directory. You can use one htaccess in document root directory to manage all your site (subdirectories included). Note that if you have htaccess in a subdirectory, it will override the root one

Answer (score 0):

You could have more than one, to use different configs in different directories, but just one per directory.